# Slicing using negative index range

Tags: python, indexing, slice

```
a = 'blueberry'

print a[-1:-3]
```

Can some explain why this prints `''`.

Is it not possible to select a range using negative indexing.

Comment: It doesn't.  It raises a `TypeError` for trying to do item-assignment with a string.

Comment: in idle it returns the following; >>> a[-1:-3]
''

Comment: I'm not getting an error message

Comment: Are you sure you posted the right code?  Doing that will always raise a `TypeError`.

Comment: It **is** possible to use negative indexing when slicing. You cannot assign a single character into a string because strings are immutable in Python.

Comment: Note that -1 is closer to the end of the string than -3, so unless you specify a negative step the slice is empty.

Comment: a[-1] is the same as a[8] in your case. a[-3] is the same as a[6]. a[8:6] does not make sense because there is negative number of items in the slice.

Comment: I think I know what you are saying.  Are you asking why `a[-1:-3]` returns an empty string?  The code you posted does not make this very clear because it looks like you are doing assignment.  Did you mean to use `==` instead of `=`?

Comment: ok this makes sense to me now, thanks Pavel and Jonrsharpe

Comment: I'm reading over slicing and a part to a question was that, just wasnt sure why it was returning ' '. Its clear now from what Pavel and Jon explained. Thanks iCodez

Comment: Right, I clarified your question.  You need to be more clear in the future.  People thought you were doing assignment.

Comment: Pavel and Jon didnt but thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are asking it to read from `-1` (the last character) to `-3` in forward direction and nothing lies beyond last character hence `''`.
The way it works is

```
a[begin:end:step]
```